# How to convert the lower case to upper case while uploading from csv file using apex and VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have some apex code and a visualforce page for uploading a CSV file to create a new Account. In my file the account is given in lower case letter.  I need to change it to uppercase.

APEX Code:

```
for (Integer i=1;i<filelines.size();i++) {
    String[] inputvalues = new String[]{};
    inputvalues = filelines[i].split(',');
    String SalesforceAccountNumber = inputvalues[2];
    Acc_Bulider = inputvalues[3];
    if(Acc_Bulider != 'Builder Unknown') {
        Account a = new Account();
        a.Name = inputvalues[3];

        acctNames.add(a.Name);
        accstoupload.add(a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try toUpperCase() method ?

```
a.Name = inputvalues[3].toUpperCase();
```

You can read more about string methods here 
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm